# Alternatives to HP Operations Orchestration and Cloud Slang

Tags: automation

HP Operations Orchestration and its community edition are nice.  I also like Cloud Slang.  But I think there has to be at least one more alternative to these platforms that enable comprehensive orchestration and automation of diverse tasks (not just backups or OS patch deployments).  I'm looking for the following features:

- automate ETL tasks
- continuous integration tasks
- deploying code patches
- rotating logs
- centralize logging of performance monitors etc. among different data centers including a public cloud

I would prefer a good SDK or API to potential automate the automation.

I'm willing to pay top dollar or use an open source solution which may attract eager talent.  Proprietary systems are great with support.  But do-it-yourself open source solutions are on the table.  Are there really just two companies behind general I.T. orchestration with a single point-of-view?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, your question is currently too broad and we would like you to narrow down your question adding things such as how much you're willing to spend, what features you're looking for, what OS, etc. Please also check out the [Question Quality Guidlines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/133)